# Change content of div with button outside that div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This question is a followup to a question asked a while ago.

Here is my block of code:

```
<head>    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>   
<body>
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="first">Instructions</a> &#8226; 
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="second">Video</a> &#8226;
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="instruction_type" data-link="first">
      <p>TEXT 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="instruction_type" data-link="second">
      <p>TEXT 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>   
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.instruction_type').hide();

  $('.link').click(function() {
    $('.instruction_type').hide();       
    $('.instruction_type[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({ width: '200px'}, 300);
  });
</script>
```

It is functional! However, currently, you load the page and see two clickable links: "Instructions" and "Video." The rest of the page is blank.

I would like the page to DEFAULT to "Instructions" and then if you click "Video" it changes the content of the page.

To be clear: functional code, want to have the page display Instructions upon loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this code to the end of your javascript:

```
$('.link:first').click();
```

This way, when the page loads, the first button is clicked..

Your javascript code would be something like this:

```
$('.instruction_type').hide();


$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.instruction_type').hide();       
    $('.instruction_type[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({ width: '200px'}, 300);
});

$('.link:first').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding both with this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.instruction_type').hide();
```

You could change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.instruction_type[data-link=second]').hide();
```

To only hide the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS instead, here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/NeUbr/)**</kbd>

```
.instruction_type {
  display: none;
}
.instruction_type:nth-child(1) { 
  display: block;
}
```

then in jQuery

```
$('.instruction_type[data-link="' + $(this).data('link') + '"]').fadeIn(300, 'linear').siblings('.instruction_type').fadeOut(300, 'linear');
```